# Nested Dynamic Content Controls with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am interested in creating a system of nested content controls to visually represent a user created network of nodes in an automation system.

Simply, I have nodes 'x' and they each contain modules 'y' which host channels 'z'.

So far I have set up in the ViewModel a system for instantiating all of this.
I have a `List<x>` where `x` is a model that contains a `List<y>` (and attributes: name, ID),
where `y` is a model that contains `List<z>`(and attributes: name, index) where `z` is a model for a channel (attributes: name, state, command).

I would now like to display these in my View.

The way I would like to do this is as follows, for each model `x` in `List<x>` there should be a Headered Content Control (or some other control) whose item-source is the `List<y>` in this model `x`. The Content Control should also display the 'name' attribute of `x`.

The datatemplate for each `y` under this Content Control should be a similar Content Control where the item-source is the `List<z>` in this model `y`. The Content Control should also display the 'name' attribute of `y`.

Finally, each model `z` under this content control should be displayed as a CheckBox that binds it's "ischecked" state to the 'state' attribute of the model, it's content to the 'name' attribute, and it's command to the 'command' attribute.

My question is; is there a way to do this in MVVM? And if so, how would I go about setting it up?

Comment: I think you just need to make a special UserControl which will have the ViewModel DataContext by which you can bind these three lists, for example `<custom:MyControl Nodes="{Binding ListX}" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, there are several ways to accomplish this task. It strongly depends on what kind of visual result you want to achieve.

You can display your data as a tree:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Module}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Channel}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding State}"
                      Command="{Binding Command}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

In this example both appearance and relation to nested items for your classes are defined by `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s. `TreeView` control is "smart" enough to know what to do with those.

More general solution would be something along these lines:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Name}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}"
                              Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding Name}">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}"
                                              Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding State}"
                                                      Content="{Binding Name}"
                                                      Command="{Binding Command}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </HeaderedContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here a template for each class is defined explicitly by `ItemTemplate` property on corresponding `ItemsControl`. I used `Margin` property for nested items to introduce some indentation.

**NOTE**

I've replaced `x`, `y` and `z` class names with `Node`, `Module` and `Channel` respectively for the sake of readability. Also, I'm using corresponding collection names - `Nodes`, `Modules` and `Channels` - which I believe should be self-explanatory.

Comment: This is way simpler than the way I actually did it. I have yet to test this variation but I am confident that it will work and is the most efficient method. For the curious; the way I did it was to create HeaderedContentControl objects in the ViewModel for each of the classes and had the view display the first in the chain.